# Unexpected characters at end of line in Keil - but there are none

Tags: c, keil, armcc

I am using Keil uVision v5.14 to compile some code for an nrf51xx cpu.
I have always used a header file called nrf_delay.h which has some delay routines encoded in assembler.
All of a sudden,  receive the above error during compilation, on all the "NOP" lines:

```
#if defined ( __CC_ARM   )
static __ASM void __INLINE nrf_delay_us(uint32_t volatile number_of_us)
{
loop
    SUBS    R0, R0, #1
    NOP
    NOP
    NOP
    NOP
    NOP
    NOP
    NOP
    NOP
    NOP
    NOP
    NOP
    NOP
    BNE    loop
    BX     LR
}
#elif defined ( __ICCARM__ )
...
```

text of error:

```
..\..\..\Include\nrf_delay.h(12): error: A1137E: Unexpected characters at end of line
..\..\..\Include\nrf_delay.h(13): error: A1137E: Unexpected characters at end of line
..\..\..\Include\nrf_delay.h(14): error: A1137E: Unexpected characters at end of line
..\..\..\Include\nrf_delay.h(15): error: A1137E: Unexpected characters at end of line
..\..\..\Include\nrf_delay.h(16): error: A1137E: Unexpected characters at end of line
..\..\..\Include\nrf_delay.h(17): error: A1137E: Unexpected characters at end of line
..\..\..\Include\nrf_delay.h(18): error: A1137E: Unexpected characters at end of line
..\..\..\Include\nrf_delay.h(19): error: A1137E: Unexpected characters at end of line
..\..\..\Include\nrf_delay.h(20): error: A1137E: Unexpected characters at end of line
..\..\..\Include\nrf_delay.h(21): error: A1137E: Unexpected characters at end of line
..\..\..\Include\nrf_delay.h(22): error: A1137E: Unexpected characters at end of line
..\..\..\Include\nrf_delay.h(23): error: A1137E: Unexpected characters at end of line
```

The weird thing it, there are absolutely no extra characters after NOP.
I have tried also substituting nrf_delay.h with an older version, or changing the project settings to match a working one, but no luck.

The whole thing is enclosed between

```
#if defined ( __CC_ARM   )
```

but I am not sure whether "_CC_ARM" or "**ICCARM**" is defined. 
The C compiler is Armcc V5.05.

**update**

I have started from a working project, and I have added the changes I have mad from last time step by step.
It seems that simply including nrf_delay.h in the new .c file of the project triggers the problem.

However, nrf_delay.h is included in many other .c files, and nrf_delay_us() is used many times with no such a problem.

**update 2 - solved, but still a mistery**
So, I have some #defines on top of my .c file.
If I put it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "fw_update.h"
#include "registers.h"
#include "nrf51.h"
#include "boarddef.h"
#include "hal.h"
#include "nrf_delay.h" <-- this is giving the error
```

if I put it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "nrf_delay.h" <-- this works!
#include "fw_update.h"
#include "registers.h"
#include "nrf51.h"
#include "boarddef.h"
#include "hal.h"
```

any idea why?

Comment: Sometimes it can be a text editor error, try deleting the lines and retyping.

Comment: Thanks @WeatherVane, not helping.

Comment: ...without using copy/paste.

Comment: @WeatherVane still not helping :)

Comment: Suspect `NOP` is `#define` someplace in `"fw_update.h" ... "hal.h"`  A simply `#ifdef NOP` before `#include "nrf_delay.h"` can confirm

Comment: indeed NOP was #define in registers.h ...

Answer (score 0):

An [unexpected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923404/unexpected-characters-at-end-of-line-in-keil-but-there-are-none#comment55614920_33923404) `#define` of `NOP` occurs in a header file.

The 12 errors corresponded to the 12 `NOP` implying an issue with `NOP` and not some line-ending issue.  Also the occurrence of the error changed relative to header placement.

Having such a short generic token `NOP` defined in some header file has these unfortunate effects.  IMO, if reasonably possible, re-factory the `#define`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error within a .s file.

Solved error A1137E by checking the checkbox "Assemble by using ArmClang V6"
In options dialog, tab ASM